# Convert this scenario into algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations

- Sales for the month minus the VAT @ 20% = (x).
- 20% of (x) is profit margin (y).
- 5% of (y) is commission earned (c).

How can I write an equation that demonstrates the above please?

I.e x - 20% of y - 95% of y = c. (Sorry, not explained well). Thanks.

Comment: What are your efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not : y = 0.2 x and c = 0.05 y. Then c = 0.05 (0.2 x) = 0.01 x

Comment: Ah yes, I see - makes sense, thanks. Would you say this is the simplest way of writing this scenario?

Comment: @Goeff Jackson. Probably the simplest I see. With that, knowing the amount of the sales (exclude VAT), you directly have the profit (y) and the commission (c). Similar things could be done satrting with the sales including VAT and compute evrything.